# How can I check if file exists in nginx? otherwise run a rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

good day everyone,

In order to resize images on the fly, i have decided to use a service like Kraken or imgix.

My images will be displayed as so: `site.com/img/path-to-img-s250x250.jpg`
and what i would like to achieve is: if the image `path-to-img-s250x250.jpg` exists, then i'll display it, and if not then run an nginx rewrite rule to resize the original image and save it.

Is this something possible or should i do the checks with PHP?

Also do you have any better ideas on how to better deal with resizing images on the fly?

Thanks a lot

```
location /img/ {
    try_files $uri @getImg @resize;
}

location @getImg{
    rewrite "img/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).([0-9]{5}).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" /img/$1/$2-$3x$4.$6 break;
}

location @resize{
    rewrite "img/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).([0-9]{5}).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" $scheme://$host/image?path=$1&file=$2&ext=$6&w=$3&h=$4 break;
}
```

and here is the image link: `site.com/img/prods/1002/filename-200x200.12345.jpg`

12345 is for the versioning

Comment: `try_files` accepts a named location in the last parameter only. Your `@getImg` term is being interpreted as a filename. Are you trying to test the presence of two alternative filenames? One with and one without a version number?

Comment: actually all images come with version number. The difference is that this image can be already stored in the hard disk, in this case i simply display it omitting the version number (`@getImg`). And the second case is if the image doesn't exist and need to generate it through Kraken.io and save it... Hope you better understand me

Comment: I have updated the answer with something that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh that's amazing, almost there :) i'm facing a problem with `@resize`: `rewrite "^/img/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).([0-9]{5}).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" $scheme://$host/image?path=$1&file=$2&ext=$6&w=$3&h=$4 break` redirects to the URL with all que query strings... :( and if i don't use `$scheme://$host` it returns a 404 error

Comment: You want to internally redirect to the `/image` handler, which I presume points to a PHP script? Depending on your script, you may need to do a `rewrite...last`, or you may need to include all of the relevant `fastcgi` statements within the @rewrite block instead.

Comment: Yes, `/image` is a Laravel Route that points to a PHP script. I tried `last` in the `rewrite`, but didn't change anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to test for the existence of one or more files.dule.html#try_files) for details.

Use a *regular expression* [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to capture the elements of the URI. Regular expression locations are evaluated in order, so there position within the configuration file may be significant. See this document for details.

If the final parameter of a `try_files` statement is a URI. it will generate an internal redirect.

For example:

```
location ~ "^/img/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{5})\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" {
    try_files $uri /img/$1/$2-$3x$4.$6 /image?path=$1&file=$2&ext=$6&w=$3&h=$4;
}
```

The above will not work on its own, as many PHP scripts use the originally requested URI (`REQUEST_URI`) to determine the route.

You can create a custom location to explicitly set the `REQUEST_URI` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameters.

For example:

```
location = /image {
    include        fastcgi_param;
    fastcgi_pass   ...;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI      $uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Base this block on your existing code (the above is just a guess). We include the global configuration files first, then override `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI`. I have assumed that `index.php` is handling the `/image` route.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your reply. I've already tried this but it's not working. I updated my initial post with my code. It actually skips `@getImg` and goes to `@resize` even if the image exists... However if i use only `try_files $uri @getImg;` () without @resize, the image is displayed correctly

Comment: Don't know how to thank you! works like a charm. Thousand thanks :)

Comment: Dear @Richard, I have updated my initial post for a little issue i'm having, would you please have a look at it? thanks

Comment: You should post it as a new question. Reopening an old question with an accepted answer will just confuse things.

Comment: It's done, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455163/how-to-proxy-frontend-images-into-backend-images Thanks :)

Comment: can you help me , please at my case https://serverfault.com/questions/1105876/rewrite-url-from-text-cache-file-otherwise-not-found-call-php-file