# How to proxy Frontend images into Backend images?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm facing a little problem to handle images. I have a Front server (site.com) and Back server (api.site.com), both linked by an NFS Storage for images.
The original images are stored in the Back server.
The Front server got only Nginx & NodeJs
The back office got only Nginx & PHP

When I want to display an image: `site.com/img/path-to-img-s250x250.jpg`, it will search it in the NFS, if it exists, it's gonna be displayed, if not, then get the original image, resize it and save it in the NFS through our PHP script in the API server.

The rewriting rules you recommended me, will work only if i want to display images through the API (`api.site.com/img/path-to-img-s250x250.jpg`), but i'll need to display images trough the Front (`site.com/img/path-to-img-s250x250.jpg`), do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

```
# site.com/img/prods/10002/filename-w200h200-bgF00.12345.jpg
location ~ "^/img/(.*)/([a-z0-9-]+)-w([0-9]+)h([0-9]+)(-bg([0-9A-Fa-f]{3,6}))?\.[0-9]{5}\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|webp)$" {
    try_files $uri /img/$1/$2-w$3h$4$5.$7 @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
    proxy_pass http://api.site.com;
    proxy_set_header X-ORIGIN http://api.site.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your previous question ([How can I check if file exists in nginx? otherwise run a rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395091/how-can-i-check-if-file-exists-in-nginx-otherwise-run-a-rewrite-rule)) you need the final redirection to be external rather than internal.

You can achieve an external redirection by specifying a named `location` as the last parameter of the `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ "^/img/(.*/[a-z0-9]+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)\.[0-9]{5}\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" {
    try_files $uri /img/$1.$2 @resize;
}
location @resize {
    rewrite "^/img/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.[0-9]{5}\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" https://api.example.com/image?path=$1&file=$2&ext=$5&w=$3&h=$4 redirect;
}
```

Comment: thanks again for your reply :)

your solution, almost works, except the fact that it redirects to the api.example URL with the query strings... :(

I have updated my initial post with a script I found after i posted the question, it actually keeps the file name intact, but just redirects the host... do you see anything wrong?

Comment: The `break` suffix is not appropriate for an external redirection. You should use `redirect` for a 302 response, and `permanent` for a 301. You should probably use `redirect`.

Comment: if I use `redirect`, the status code of the image is 302 which I'm not sure it's a good idea for SEO and Location is Response Headers shows the `api.site.com...` link! any possible way to make this as transparent as possible?

Comment: You are updating your cache, right? So you do not want a permanent redirection. You could mask the entire process by using `proxy_pass` instead. But I do not understand why you need to split this across two separate servers.

Comment: yes or course, i always clear cache for tests. I need to split this across 2 separate servers because the original images are saved in the backend server (API) that can't be accessible for public, and public images are stored in the Front server. the resize and save process can only be done with the API. do you recommend a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi @Richard, I'm almost there, I've updated my initial post with the new code, but the only problem is that the `try_files` doesn't display the image through `/img/$1/$2-w$3h$4$5.$7` even if it exists, it always regenerate it and don't know why. for memo, these rules are set in the Front server. do you see anything wrong plz? also, do you have any recommendation or better architecture of what i'm trying to do?